# Tableau Public Background Images Not Working

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, business-intelligence

I'm using Tableau Public and would like to include a background image for my dashboard. When I go to Map --> Background Images , nothing populates. I see the right arror, but when I scroll over it I don't have the option to go any further. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you feel the answer is correct, please accept it so we can close the topic ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're referring to (Map -> Backgroung images) is **just for worksheets**.

Background images are strictly related to your data in order to plot markers on a specifc image according to data valuues
(https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/background-images)

That being said, if you need "just" an **image as a background for your dashboard**, it's quite simple:

- In the Object section select a "Image" element and drag it into the dashboard
- Place your woorksheet(s) into the dashboard with the floating option (not tiled) in order to bring them forward (if needed)
- Extra: if you need the background image to be readable, remember to set your worksheet deafault shading value to none